# How to check if there is new data after updated a form?

Tags: php, mysql

I’ve made a small cms from scratch with PHP.

I have a classic system of articles and categories (like in Joomla, WordPress, etc.).

Users can order articles. So i have a column "order" in "article" table with number : 1, 2 ,3 etc.

Users can also change categories. So i need to modify order column after changing categories, otherwise i can have an order like this 1, 3, 4 in previous category and 1, 2, 2, 4 in new category.

I’ve made a script that reconstruct order in each category. It works.

But i don’t know how to check when i need it.

My code :

```
// $new_category : new category selected by user in a select"
// $categorie : $_GET['categorie']

if ($new_category !== $categorie) {

// reconstruct order column

}
```

`if ($new_category !== $categorie)`, it doesn’t work very well because after the article is updated, the parameter `$_GET['categorie']` in URL doesn’t change. If user change again category, it could result in errors in order column.

So, i thought about compare between new category and category stored in database. But, since the database is updated before column order is reconstructed, it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it doesn’t work very well because after the article is updated, the
>   parameter $_GET['categorie'] in URL doesn’t change

In general, you should never update the database from a GET, only from a POST. A common thing to do in this situation is a [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) -- this will allow a user to change the category and then will refresh the page so that it reloads with the new one, which will allow them to change it again. If you want to add a re-ordering process in there, you can put it between the Post and Redirect steps, and the subsequent GET will receive the newly updated order.